# System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.?

Tags: c#

Ok I keep getting the error in the title I am not actually sure why. You can see the first part of the code in a method where I add things to the file and the other part is when I read from the file.

Well I tried to close the file as i googled but I just keep getting errors.

```
if (File.Exists("important.txt"))
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("important.txt"))
        writer.Write("\r\n" + name + "," + socialid + "," + town + "," +  numsold);
}
else
{ 
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("important.txt"))
    {
        writer.Write(name + "," + socialid + "," + town + "," + numsold);
    }
```

---

```
System.IO.StreamReader file =  new System.IO.StreamReader("important.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] array = line.Split(',');
    int num1 = Int32.Parse(array[3]);
    if(num1 < 50)
    {
        str2 = line.Replace(",", " ");
        System.Console.WriteLine(str2);
        counter++;
    }
}
file.Close();
```

I am not even sure what causes this problem to happen and well googling for fixes gave no results.

Comment: Are they running simultaneously?

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar I am not sure I am new to C# but I don't think they would ever run simultaneously.

Comment: And what line produces the error?

Comment: Get your StreamReader into a `using` statement

Comment: @HenkHolterman using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("important.txt"))

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead:

```
string path = @"C:\\important.txt";
if (File.Exists(path))
     File.AppendAllText(path,"\r\n" + name + "," + socialid + "," + town + "," + numsold);
else
     File.AppendAllText(path, name + "," + socialid + "," + town + "," + numsold);

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    string[] array = line.Split(',');
    int num1 = Int32.Parse(array[3]);
    if(num1 < 50)
    {
        str2 = line.Replace(",", " ");
        System.Console.WriteLine(str2);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason for the foreach?

Comment: @jondoe it’s possible with regular for loop as well

Comment: I meant what is the reason of you using a for loop?

Comment: @jondoe Because in your code you done the same with `while` loop for iterating all lines..

Comment: So no real differenve between my while loopcode and your for loops in this case?